# Остановка цикла нажатием клавиши, библиотека pynput

Tags: threading, pynput

Написал код, который в бесконечном цикле через библиотеку pynput юзает клаву и мышку, но теперь нужно включать/выключать этот цикл нажатием клавиши, скажем пробела. Без цикла я это реализовать могу, но, при попытке объеденить два кода не работает либо одно, либо другое. Я знаю в чём заключается проблема, в потоках, нужно запустить выполнение цикла в одном потоке, а проверку на нажатие в другом, но вот как это реализовать-не знаю

```
import time, pynput, threading

mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()
keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()

count=0
flag=True

def press(key):
    print("ееххууу")

def release(key):
    if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.space:
        flag=False

while flag: 
    print("Цикл: "+str(count))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Up")
    keyboard.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.up)
    keyboard.release(pynput.keyboard.Key.up)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Enter")
    keyboard.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("L click")
    mouse.click(pynput.mouse.Button.left)
    count=count+1


with pynput.keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=press,
        on_release=release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Подробно описано, как остановить нитку - https://superfastpython.com/stop-a-thread-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

```
import time, pynput, threading

mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()
keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()

count=0
count1=10
flag=True

def press(key):
    global flag
    if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.space:
        print("gg")
        flag=False

def loop_fun():
    global count1
    for number in range(10): 
        print("Старт через: "+str(count1))
        time.sleep(1)
        count1=count1-1

    global count
    global flag
    while flag: 
        print("Цикл: "+str(count))
        time.sleep(0)
        print("Up")
        keyboard.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.up)
        keyboard.release(pynput.keyboard.Key.up)
        time.sleep(0)
        print("Enter")
        keyboard.press(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(pynput.keyboard.Key.enter)
        time.sleep(0)
        print("L click")
        mouse.click(pynput.mouse.Button.left)
        count=count+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    abortKey = 'space'
    listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=press, abortKey=abortKey)
    listener.start()  # start to listen on a separate thread

    # start thread with loop
    threading.Thread(target=loop_fun, args=(), name='loop_fun', daemon=True).start()

    listener.join() # wait for abortKey
```